# How is this React useReducer handler an impure function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I'm seeing unexpected results from React.StrictMode calling my useReducer function twice - I am swapping elements in an array, but StrictMode is causing my swap to jump elements two slots instead of the desired once. I'm not sure what is 'impure' about this code?

```
case 'swap_section': {

   let modified_song = {...song}

   let target_section_index = modified_song.song.songsheet.aSections.findIndex(
          section => action.daw ===  section.daw
   ) 
   let target_section = modified_song.song.songsheet.aSections[target_section_index] 
   let swap_section_index = action.direction === "down" 
                 ? target_section_index + 1 :  target_section_index - 1

   // StrictMode calling this twice may attempt to swap w/ (final index + 1) - check index & undefined
        if(swap_section_index > -1 && swap_section_index < modified_sections.length) {
            let swap_section = modified_song.song.songsheet.aSections[swap_section_index]
            if(swap_section) {
                modified_song.song.songsheet.aSections[swap_section_index] = target_section
                modified_song.song.songsheet.aSections[target_section_index] = swap_section
                return modified_song
            }
        }
   return modified_song 
}
```

Comment: It's the way how react18 works, having StrictMode on for a dev build will trigger your hook twice (not sure about all hooks, but useEffect at least and it seems like your useReducer too), however it won't be the case for your production build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), because the value `song.song` from the outside is modified *(I'm assuming "outside" to be the code which you haven't shown)*.

#### Object identity

You apparently intended to create a copy of the `song` object, but your approach doesn't "deep copy" the object, i.e. this line:

```
let modified_song = {...song}
```

copies all properties of `song` into `modified_song`, and `modified_song` is now an object different to `song`, but all the properties of `modified_song` still have the same (identical) values as the properties of `song`, i.e. `modified_song.song` is identical to `song.song`.

Now when you modify `modified_song.song`, you are also modifying `song.song` (and the next time the code is executed, the input is different).

#### Solution

You need to copy the last properties, keep the original unchanged, and work only with the copy, e.g.:

```
// -- WRONG: --
// modified_song.song.songsheet.aSections[swap_section_index] = target_section
// modified_song.song.songsheet.aSections[target_section_index] = swap_section
// return modified_song

// -- RIGHT: --
return {
    swap_section_index: target_section,
    target_section_index: swap_section
};
```

#### Modify the original

Changing `modified_song.song...` directly is not the way you should do it in React.

If you think you need to write the result back into `song.song...`, there probably is some way to refactor the state management, or you would invoke the state change inside some event, ... but I can't tell really, I'd need to have more information to find a specific solution.